# How to use track bar in NAudio MP3 streaming section

Tags: c#, naudio

I am using NAudio Library in C# and I need a track bar to control the music. In NAudio Mp3Stream example project we have standard controls such as play, stop, pause, volume but there is no track bar.

Can I use track bar in Mp3Stream at all ? because when I set the break point on do command, CanSeek property is false in readFullyStream variable.

How can I use track bar on streaming ?

```
using (var responseStream = resp.GetResponseStream())
{
var readFullyStream = new ReadFullyStream(responseStream);
do
{
    if (IsBufferNearlyFull)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Buffer getting full, taking a break");
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
    else
    {
        Mp3Frame frame;
        try
        {
            frame = Mp3Frame.LoadFromStream(readFullyStream);
        }
        catch (EndOfStreamException)
        {
            fullyDownloaded = true;
            // reached the end of the MP3 file / stream
            break;
        }
        catch (WebException)
        {
            // probably we have aborted download from the GUI thread
            break;
        }
        if (decompressor == null)
        {
            // don't think these details matter too much - just help ACM select the right codec
            // however, the buffered provider doesn't know what sample rate it is working at
            // until we have a frame
            decompressor = CreateFrameDecompressor(frame);
            bufferedWaveProvider = new BufferedWaveProvider(decompressor.OutputFormat);
            bufferedWaveProvider.BufferDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20); // allow us to get well ahead of ourselves
            //this.bufferedWaveProvider.BufferedDuration = 250;
        }
        int decompressed = decompressor.DecompressFrame(frame, buffer, 0);
        //Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Decompressed a frame {0}", decompressed));
        bufferedWaveProvider.AddSamples(buffer, 0, decompressed);
    }

} while (playbackState != StreamingPlaybackState.Stopped);
Debug.WriteLine("Exiting");
// was doing this in a finally block, but for some reason
// we are hanging on response stream .Dispose so never get there
decompressor.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the NAudio streaming demo simply decompresses and plays MP3 frames as they arrive. There is no code to store previously received audio. So if you wanted the ability to rewind, you'd need to implement that.

One option you could consider is using the `MediaFoundationReader`, passing in the stream URL as the path. This can play audio as it downloads, and should support repositioning as well.